# How to implement lesssignificant24bytes Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mastercard

Example :

Input (accountId): 63617264686F6C6465726E616D654077616C6C657470726F 76696465722E636F6D

Expected Output : 123CCB2F30BA420B17F837DF60E2FC9D6965A74476849FC D43A640F792A2B358

```
public String accountIdHash (String accountId)
{
String random8Bytes = 123CCB2F30BA420B
return random8Bytes + lessSignificant24bytes(strongerHash(accountId + random8Bytes))
} 

public String strongerHash(String dataToHash)
{
    String currentHash = dataToHash; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
    currentHash = sha256(currentHash);
    } 
    return sha256(sha256(dataToHash) + currentHash);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that applying a hash function 5000 times makes a stronger hash? It can only get weaker in each round.

Comment: I think we're going to need a more detailed specification for `lessSignificant24bytes()`...

Comment: Thanks all, I'm using this Hashing method to solve the requirment for the MasterCard issue. 
Just I need to know what's lessSignificant24bytes Implementation method to give me output correctly.

Comment: the description  : 
 String random8BKnowytes =123CCB2F30BA420B”
Hash calculation example:
• email address: cardholdername@walletprovider.com
• accountid as Input: 63617264686F6C6465726E61
6D654077616C6C657470726F 7669646
5722E636F6D
• random8Bytes: 123CCB2F30BA420B
• output: 123CCB2F30BA420B17F837DF
60E2FC9D6965A74476849FC D43A640F
792A2B358